# "Через" с приблизительными данными о времени

Tags: предлоги, стилистика

В зависимости от того, точные ли или приблизительные данные имеются в виду, в словосочетаниях `число` + `единица измерения` единица измерения ставится либо в конце ("сто грамм"), либо в начале ("грамм сто").

Среди прочего это правило распространяется и на временые промежутки: "три дня" / "дня три".

**Каким образом видоизменяется словосочетание в связи с добавлением предлога "через"?** С точным значением все понятно ("через три дня"), а с приблизительным не совсем. Есть два варианта: "дня через три" и "через дня три". Первый кажется мне единственным стилистически правильным, второй сильно режет ухо. **Есть ли правило, регулирующее этот случай?**

Comment: На мой вкус - первый вариант единственно правильный. Правил не знаю, ориентируюсь инстинктивно.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта правильные. Когда Вы ставите единицу измерения перед числом, это означает, что вы говорите о какой-то приблизительной, оценочной величине. Например, "переезд займёт у нас дня два" означает, что скорее всего переезд займёт два дня, но Вы не уверены в этом. Может быть и три, и четыре.

Так же когда Вы употребляете число + единицу измерения с предлогом "через". Например, "я приеду через дня три" означает, что скорее всего Вы приедете через три дня, а может через два или четыре. Кстати, чаще говорят "через + единица измерения + число", т.е. меняют порядок слов. Например, "дня через три", а не "через дня три".

Answer (score 1):

Приблизительность и точность к вашему вопросу относятся лишь косвенно. Вопрос скорее о месте предлога в словосочетании. Предлог - это по сути отделённая часть слова, которая стоит перед ним. Если слово с предлогом является главным в словосочетании, то зависимые от него слова могут стоять перед предлогом: *он шёл через* **большой лиственный лес**.

Главным в словосочетании *три дня* является числительное, поэтому предлог стремится к нему. Чаще всего, если зависимое слово не выражено прилагательным, то его перед предлогом стараются не ставить (отсюда резь в ухе), но правилами это не запрещено, поэтому возможны оба сочетания, но более благозвучное *дня через три*.

Правда когда подобный вопрос обсуждался на русскоязычном форуме, со мной были согласны не все. Аргументы обеих сторон можно посмотреть по [ссылке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/34484/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0/34491#34491).